# How do I change my terminal’s cursor from a block to a blinking vertical bar?

Tags: terminal

Currently I'm using Intellij and ZSH as terminal. I already have disabled the caret block for Intellij and want to do the same for ZSH terminal. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: _ZSH as terminal_ .... ZSH is not a terminal; it is a shell. A shell does not have any idea of a cursor. Also this is not something related to programming, but to the configuration of your terminal program. Hence the question should be posted at [su]; and drop the `zsh` tags, since the question is also unrelated to zsh.

Comment: I really wish there was a way to _move_ questions between SE sites, not just close them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the cursor shape is not specific to Zsh but depends on whether your terminal supports it. The are two ways to change the cursor shape in the terminal:

- Many terminals allow you to choose in their settings what kind of cursor you want. Check your terminal's preferences  and change it there.
- If your terminal doesn't have any config for this, you can try adding `echo '\e[5 q'` to your `.zshrc` file (when using Zsh) or `.bashrc` file (when using Bash) to tell your terminal to draw a blinking bar as the cursor. However, in this case, too, it depends on whether your terminal supports that escape code. If it doesn't, nothing will change.

---

Also, for clarity:

- Zsh and Bash are [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)).
- You interact with the shell through a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator).
- IntelliJ IDEA has an integrated terminal through which you interact with Zsh.
- Any other app you use to interact with your shell is a terminal, too.

Comment: Adding echo '\e[5 q' to .zshrc worked. Thank you!